Which Gallows puzzle corresponds to Angela, Eddie, and James?
When aiming for the specific endings, per online sources, pulling the gallows connected to either James, Angela, or Eddie affects the ending you get.

 I feel pretty confident that Eddie is the murderer, based on the crime matching and the endings matching Eddie's anger and history with bullying:


     I waited long, I bid my time, I waited to commit my crime, The man appeared, he saw me not, A bloody end is what he got.


     In truth, he was less man than beast, And on my flesh and soul he'd feast, My will to live he'd try to break, There is so much a man can take.


    In truth, I did not hesitate, As my blade sealed the poor man's fate, He knew the rules, they are quite clear, Go against me, your end is near.


 But Angela and James I feel more confused by. Angela could be the prisoner who killed his mother since they both killed their parents:


    Mommy dearest, mommy sweet, Your love for me was so deep, "Why, oh, why?", you shouted out, When my knife pierced through your heart.


but either conclusion could also fit for James, since they both involve killing somebody either as revenge for ruining their life or despite the unquestioning love they showed, both of which are heavy thematic elements in the game:


    You broke my legs, I couldn't walk, You pulled my teeth, I couldn't talk, You fed me pills to slow my mind, I took your life 'fore you took mine.


    You were, oh, so kind to me, Filled my heart with joy and glee, In the end, it was for naught, "Why, oh, why?", you ask. Why not?


 I could also see Angela as the kidnapper because of the second halves, both of which would nicely match Angela's relationship with her mother and father either ironically or not:


    Forgive me, child, for I have failed, To save you from her wretched ways, She whom I loved, who gave you life, A monster hiding in plain sight.


    My only daughter, joy of days, They wanted to take you away, Hush, little baby, and be still, If I can't have you, no one will.

In summary, there's a whole list of crimes that could apply to James and Angela, some only match the first stanza and some only match the second stanza, and I can't find anything online about which victim definitively corresponds to which character.
